# Unpivot the columns into rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have one row with an unknown number of columns. I need to unpivot all those columns into one column. Here is an example. I start with this table

```
select 1 as c1, 2 as c2, 3 as c3
into tempP
```

If we select this table the result will be

```
c1  c2  c3
1   2   3
```

I want the result to be this

```
new_name
1
2
3
```

Also, remember that I don't know if I will have 3 columns. I might have 100 columns, but the number of rows will always be 1. Thanks.

Comment: That is not a pivot, the process of converting columns into rows is an unpivot.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I didn't know that. I will edit the question.

Comment: This might be better done in application code. The way you describe it, it seems like a display issue, not a data issue.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' no no. I might be able to say that (or not), but I would like to know simply if that is possible and if so how to do that (using TSQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bluefeet mentioned in your comments section you will need an `UNPIVOT` query for this not a Pivot query.

One thing you need to be careful about, the data type should be the same for all the columns you are Unpivoting.

Something like this....

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(c1 INT , c2 INT, c3 INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1,   2,   3),
(10, 20,  30)

SELECT NewColumn
FROM @TABLE 
 UNPIVOT (NewColumn FOR allcols IN ([c1],[c2],[c3]) ) up
```

### Result:

```
NewColumn
1
2
3
10
20
30
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is it possible to do the unpivot without specifying the previous column names? Like use a star or something. The thing is that I want to a query that will do that operation without knowing the names and the amount of the columns.

Comment: No you cannot use star, you will need to use the column names explicitly, if you do not know what will be the column names, then you will need to use dynamic sql to get the column names dynamically , and its not simple at all, a bit tricky query, best use the column names explicitly and avoid using dynamic sql.